Use notebook exit value in calling notebook
I have a main (parent) notebook which is calling another notebook (child), using dbutils.notebook.run.  If the child notebook fails I return a failure message using dbutils.notebook.exit("Error Message").  How can I return and use that message in the parent notebook?
Thanks for the help.

In your child you would have this
dbutils.notebook.exit("Error Message")

In your parent notebook you would have something like this.
result = dbutils.notebook.run("./Child_notebook")

print(f" The result from the child notebook is {result}")

You can refer to the official documentation as well.

Thanks.  I am using futures to call a function which then calls the notebook.  `import concurrent.futures
max_workers = 40
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
executor.map(run_notebook, table_collection)`   If the word "error" exists in the result I want to raise an exception and have the parent notebook fail.  Can you help with that?

Please update the questio  with these details. Also add a code sample of what you've done and what you expect
